# load balance instance out of service after I reboot the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

The instance in the group of load balance will `out of service`

So I need to manually remove the instance from the load balance then add it back again.

How should I reboot instances in load balance group in a better way

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7H4M.png]

Answer (score 0):

EC2 instances should be removed from load balancers before they are stopped or rebooted. Once the instances are running again, add them back into the load balancer.

1. Deregister from load balancer
2. Stop and restart instance, or reboot
3. Register with load balancer

Comment: thanks~~~ :) i was thinking is there any easier way to do so

Comment: @BestPractices in theory that is correct. However, in practice, it does not always work like that. I've seen many cases where the instance never returns to `InService` without first deregistering and re-registering. After discussing the issue with AWS support, they suggested the above sequence to me to ensure things return to normal. After following this sequence, I have not had any more issues.